# Thumb injury, actuate dropper post with index finger?

Tags: mountain-bike, dropper

My partner has a thumb injury on the left hand that makes the long-throw pressing of a dropper post lever impossible. Are there other trigger mechanisms that could be swapped in to allow using the index finger or a different motion to actuate the dropper post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a bit of searching I came up with the [Wolf Tooth "ReMote 360"](https://www.wolftoothcomponents.com/products/remote-360) that looks like it should do the trick. It can be pulled or pushed in any direction. Kinda pricey at ~$60 USD (in December 2023) for a lever, but it looks well made.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The X-Fusion Manic lever is much cheaper and I believe it allows the lever to be flipped the opposite direction from normal to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This could be mounted on the right side (assuming his injury is left. https://www.jensonusa.com/Race-Face-Turbine-R-Dropper-23X-Lever-Black?loc=usa&gad_source=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiAkKqsBhC3ARIsAEEjuJjH4OAOJiheZimX0IgStMnob9z1b1BV8jtUCjaY2n3UIux3z3e7Af8aAn6qEALw_wcB

Answer (score 1):

For reference, electric droppers (SRAM AXS, Magura Vyron) could also be a solution - but more expensive, as the control on the handle bar is then just a button, that doesn't require a long-throw pressing.